# Can't get values from $form in submit handler?

Tags: webforms, forms

Using Drupal 7 and a custom form generated with the Webform module, I'm trying to get info from the submitted form to save in additional SQL tables.

I know my submit handler is being called because putting `dpm('This is great news, our submit handler is being called!');` inside the submit handler gives the expected output. So does `dpm($myvariable);` (after setting a value for `$myvariable`).

But `dpm($form);` not only doesn't return anything, but also seems to preven the other dpm() functions from working. There are no errors logged, and the page loads otherwise normally.

I should also mention that if I put the `dpm($form)` in the `hook_form_alter()` function instead of the submit handler, it does show up, but all values appear to be default or empty, after the form is submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your submit handler signatures once ... Ideally submit function should be something like below... You can try using drupal set message for same like code given below !

```
function form_example_tutorial_7_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  drupal_set_message("I am inside submit handler. Printed form values below");
  drupal_set_message("<pre>" . print_r($form_state['values'], 1) . "</pre>");
  // $form_state['values'] is used to extract submitted values !
  drupal_set_message("Printing Form Structure Below !");
  drupal_set_message("<pre>" . print_r($form, 1) . "</pre>");
}
```

Comment: $form_state['values'] was indeed what I needed. I'm still perplexed as to why $form displays nothing though?